# How to call function from child component when parent component data has loaded (Angular 5)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, vimeo, vimeo-player

I have a parent component `program-page.component` in this component I am calling  a function to get some data

```
ngOnInit() {
this.getProgress();
}

getFirstProgramItem() {
   this._contentfulService.getProgramItem(4, 1)
    .then((programItem) => {
     this.programItem = programItem;
   }).then(() => {
     console.log(this.programItem);
   });
}

getProgress() {
this._trackingService.getLastItemProgress()
  .subscribe((result) => {
    this.progress = result;
    if (this.progress.sysID == null || undefined) {
      this.getFirstProgramItem();
    }
  });
}
```

then in my **program-page.component.html**

```
<app-program-header></app-program-header>
<app-week-display></app-week-display>
<app-program-item [item]="programItem"></app-program-item>
```

I am passing in the programItem data.. then In my `program-item.component.ts`
I am getting the data and populating it

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, ParamMap, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Entry } from 'contentful';
import { ContentfulService } from '../../../contentful.service';

declare var Player: any;
declare var Vimeo: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-program-item',
  templateUrl: './program-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./program-item.component.scss']
})
export class ProgramItemComponent implements OnInit {

@Input() item: Entry<any>;

constructor(
    private contentfulService: ContentfulService
) { }

ngOnInit() {} 

loadVideo() {
   const video = new Vimeo.Player('video');
}
```

**program-item.component.html**

```
<div class="program-item">
<div class="main">
    <p *ngIf="item?.fields.asset[0].fields.textBlock" class="program-item_textblock">{{item?.fields.asset[0].fields.textBlock}}</p>
    <div id="video-panel">
      <div *ngIf="item?.fields.asset[0].fields.vimeoId" [attr.data-vimeo-id]="item?.fields.asset[0].fields.vimeoId" data-vimeo-responsive="1" id="video"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

now what I want to happen is when/after the data is loaded call the `loadVideo()`function

Ive tried using ngAfterContentInit but that didnt do anything

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: you can use the ngOnChanges function and check the `item` in through the parameter `SimpleChanges`.

Comment: @elvis_ferns sorry could you please elaborate? what is `SimpleChanges`

Comment: whenever any of the @Input data changes `ngOnChanges` is called with a parameter `SimpleChanges` that contains the old and the new value of the input. 


Refer [OnChanges](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges)

Comment: @elvis_ferns hey thanks that worked!

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that **ngAfterContentInit** gets called each time your content gets changed on the page/component, and if you have defined it in your parent, that gets loaded on each tick/ click you do on an application. This would not be a smarter way to access your child component. 
There are two approaches to  interact with child components, ad get what you want:

- Use an Emiterr
- Use @ViewChild

1)If its any data from child, that you want to see in parent, make use of Event Emitter, here are a few good refrence for it:

[Angular 2 Custom Event Binding + EventEmitter Example](https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-custom-event-binding-eventemitter-example)

[Passing data to and from a nested component in Angular 2](https://www.themarketingtechnologist.co/building-nested-components-in-angular-2/)

2)If you just want to call a child class method from parent, you can make use of Child Component in your parent as following:

```
@ViewChild(ProgramItemComponent ) child:ProgramItemComponent;
this.child.loadVideo();
```